# Row bind multiple columns into two columns containing unique elements in order

Tags: r, loops, rbind, mutate

I'm still little new to R and was wondering if I there was an easy way of manipulating the below df to achieve df2.

I'm not sure if it's a loop that is supposed to be used for this, but basically I want to take a distinct on each V(X)_ID column and it's corresponding V(X)_No column. If the V(X)_ID is repeated in further columns, I would like to ignore it and move the next unique V(X)_ID and its associated V(X)_No.

```
V1_ID <- c('AUD','CAD','NZD','USD',NA,NA,NA)
V1_No <- c(3.43,2.42,1.58,9.9,NA,NA,NA)
V2_ID <- c('TRY','AUD','EUR','SPY','TRY','BTC',NA)
V2_No <- c(8.4,2.4,6.8,1.2,9.8,9.8,NA)
V3_ID <- c('JPY','EUR','NZD','AUD','SPY','NA',NA)
V3_No <- c(1.8,8.6,4.4,2.1,9.6,NA,NA)
V4_ID <- c('GBP','TRY','HKD','SKD','USD','NZD','CAD')
V4_No <- c(1.3,4.6,7.9,8.5,2.6,7.4,9.1)
df <- data.frame(V1_ID,V1_No,V2_ID,V2_No,V3_ID,V3_No,V4_ID,V4_No)


ID <- c('AUD','CAD','NZD','USD','TRY','EUR','SPY','BTC','JPY','GBP','SKD')
No <- c(3.43,2.42,1.58,9.9,8.4,6.8,1.2,9.8,1.8,1.3,8.5)
df2 <- data.frame(ID,No)
```

Your assistance is much appreciated as I have 387 of these types of columns in this type of format and approaching it from a manual standpoint is very draining, thus am looking for hopefully a more elegant solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c("set", ".value"), names_sep = "_") |> 
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE) |> 
  drop_na() |> 
  select(-set)

# A tibble: 12 × 2
   ID       No
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 AUD    3.43
 2 TRY    8.4 
 3 JPY    1.8 
 4 GBP    1.3 
 5 CAD    2.42
 6 EUR    8.6 
 7 NZD    1.58
 8 HKD    7.9 
 9 USD    9.9 
10 SPY    1.2 
11 SKD    8.5 
12 BTC    9.8
```

There is a twelfth row though that appears that doesn't match with your desired output, and I don't know what logical step I'm missing.

Comment: You're not missing a logical step. OP has two AUD values in his ouput, though previously states that such is not desired. Frankly a little difficult to discern the logic.